# How to delete file after success copy

Tags: c#

I am trying to to delete file after successful copy.
I want the original file to be deleted after I copied it.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        string filename = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + id.ToString()+Path.GetExtension(open.FileName);
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\AttachedFiles"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "\\AttachedFiles");
        }
        File.Copy(open.FileName, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\AttachedFiles", filename));
        cnx.ExecuteCmd("insert into Attachement values('" + id + "','" + filename + "','" + Path.GetFileName(open.FileName) + "')");
        MessageBox.Show("attached success");
        listBox1.DataSource = cnx.SelectCmd("select * from Attachement where Accidentid='" + id + "'");
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "RealFilename";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Filename";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Copy` and not [`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: i try move but its not working right with me

Comment: _"i try move but its not working right with me"_ - what do you mean by that? Do you get an exception - if so, please give details.

Comment: @binkiteb Can you explain how it isn't working? Does it throw an exception (what exception?)? It almost sounds like you don't have delete permissions on the source file, or the source file is in use. If either of these are the case, then you don't have any more luck with Copy/Delete in terms of removing the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a File you can use

```
File.Delete(filePath)
```

But why don't move it with a single command instead?

```
File.Move(filePathSource, filePathDestination);
```

If you can't delete or move a file, you probably still have a Stream open.

Here a working example, how to use an `OpenFileDialog` and delete and copy the selected file.

```
using (File.Create(@"c:\Temp\txt.txt")); // File.Create wrapped in a using() to ensure disposing the stream.

using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.Copy(ofd.FileName, ofd.FileName + "2.txt");
        File.Delete(ofd.FileName);
        File.Delete(ofd.FileName + "2.txt");
    }
}
```

Notice, that i wrap a `using(...)` around the `File.Create()`. This is because it opens a Stream to the File, which locks it. If you remove the `using(...)` around the `File.Create()` the deletion will not work.

To understand why you can't delete your File, you have to search your code for any access to the file.